# On ducklings and robins

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Could someone please help me with this probability question? I've already determined that for (a), the probability of selecting at least 2 robins once is
$$
\frac{\binom83\binom32}{\binom{11}5}
+
\frac{\binom82\binom33}{\binom{11}5}
$$
Now I'm wondering about (b) and (c).

Thank you for your help in advance.

> Let's revisit the box of ducklings and robins. The box has 8 ducklings and 3 robins.
>
> (a) If you remove 5 items from the box, what is the probability you will get at least 2 robins?
>   (b) If you do this every day for a month, then average your results, what is the probability you will average getting at least 2 robins?
>   (c) What is the probability that the total number of robins you pull over the course of the month is less than 10?

Comment: Which month?????

Comment: btw, there are only 3 robins to choose from...

Comment: for (a) did you mean "choose" rather than "remove"?    $\\$                         for (b), is the box replenished every day?

Comment: To answer hypergeometric's questions, (a) yes 'choose' makes sense as well in this context, and (b) yes, the box is replenished every day.

Comment: To ask further on 'remove': is it the case that you choose one and remove it or do you simply choose it and then choose a random one again?